# Java - Circles with lines connecting the centers

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JFrame` with a subclass, `Paint_Panel`. `Paint_Panel` extends `JPanel` and implements a `MouseListener`.

I need to place three circles with mouse clicks. No problem. I have a button (Draw) that should draw lines from each circle's center to the other (thus - a triangle). I can maintain the coordinates within an `ArrayList` - no problem. However, when I try to reference the `ArrayList` by clicking the button, the list is returned empty. The Array isn't in memory at the time it is needed to draw the lines. Thoughts?

**Note**- Circles are hard-coded at 40.

Code:

```
public class Paint_Panel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    public static int flag = 0;
    boolean drawCircles = false;
    boolean drawLines = false;
    private final ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();

    public Paint_Panel() {
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    //Method to draw lines from point to point
    public void drawLines() {
        Graphics g = getGraphics();
        drawLines = true;
        paintComponent(g);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (drawCircles) {
            for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
                //Circle number 1
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.fillOval(points.get(0).x - 20, points.get(0).y - 20, 40, 40);
                //Circle number 2
                if (points.size() >= 2) {
                    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    g.fillOval(points.get(1).x - 20, points.get(1).y - 20, 40, 40);
                }
                //Circle number 3
                if (points.size() >= 3) {
                    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    g.fillOval(points.get(2).x - 20, points.get(2).y - 20, 40, 40);
                }
            }
        } else if (drawLines) {      
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);    //Set line color
            g.drawLine(points.get(0).x, points.get(0).y, points.get(1).x, points.get(1).y);
            g.drawLine(points.get(1).x, points.get(1).y, points.get(2).x, points.get(2).y);
            g.drawLine(points.get(2).x, points.get(2).y, points.get(0).x, points.get(0).y);
        }
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {  //Place circles for click event

        Graphics g = getGraphics();
        if (!drawCircles) {
            prevX = evt.getX() - 20;    //Allows placement at center. Size - radius
            prevY = evt.getY() - 20;
            points.add(evt.getPoint()); //Add point to ArrayList
            if (flag < 3) {             //Keep track of how many circles are placed
                flag += 1;
                drawCircles = true;
                paintComponent(g);
            } else if (flag == 3) {     //If additional circles attempted, inform user
                flag = 4;
                System.out.println("Only 3 circles allowed."); //Debug
                drawCircles = false;
            }
        }
        drawCircles = false;
    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) { //Unused
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt) { //Unused
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) { //Unused
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt) { //Unused
    }
}
```

Comment: why is your arraylist `final`?

Comment: instead of manually getting graphics and manually calling `paintComponent()` you should call `repaint()`. Also, why are you using a for-loop and drawing all three circles `points.size()` number of times.

Comment: Indeed, as @WhiteNightFury suggests, **don't** call `paintComponent(g)`. You shouldn't be getting your Graphics object that way either. There should be no call to `getGraphics()` in your code unless you call this on a BufferedImage. Instead use your MouseListener to set the data point fields and call `repaint()`.

Comment: @GeorgeG: I see no down side towards the OP declaring the ArrayList final. Why the question?

Comment: Check out the [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info) link to be found associated with the [tag:swing] tag. It will give you links to the Swing graphics tutorials, and I suggest that you give those a look to see how Oracle recommends that you do this.

Comment: Changing to repaint(); was attempted and yes, preferrable. However, this has no affect and no circles are rendered at all. The reason for the loop was to cycle through the three circles and maintain each circle. If this was not done, a resize would cause previous circles to disappear.

Comment: You are not supposed to cancel the `paintComponent()` method altogether (thus, the drawing of the circles). Just don't call it directly (from `mouseClicked()` and `drawLines()` and instead call `repaint()`.

Comment: Show your latest attempt where you use the MouseListener to change fields, where you use those fields to change your drawing in your paintComponent method, where you don't call paintComponent directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to draw 3 circles and 3 lines.  Edited to draw the circles first, then the lines.  Edited again to check for an invalid button press.

[image: Circle Paint Test]
[image: Circle Paint Test]

I separated the view and controller logic.

Here's the runnable code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CirclePaintTest implements Runnable {

    private JFrame frame;

    private PaintPanel paintPanel;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Circle Paint Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        paintPanel = new PaintPanel();
        mainPanel.add(paintPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        JButton lineButton = new JButton("Draw Lines");
        lineButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                if (paintPanel.isComplete()) {
                    paintPanel.setDrawLines(true);
                    paintPanel.repaint();
                }
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(lineButton);

        mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.add(mainPanel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new CirclePaintTest());
    }

    public class PaintPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 6481890334304291711L;

        private final Color[] colors = { Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE,
                Color.ORANGE, Color.CYAN, Color.YELLOW };

        private boolean drawLines;

        private final int pointLimit;

        private final List<Point> points;

        public PaintPanel() {
            this.points = new ArrayList<Point>();
            this.pointLimit = 3;
            this.drawLines = false;

            this.addMouseListener(new CircleMouseListener());
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        }

        public void setDrawLines(boolean drawLines) {
            this.drawLines = drawLines;
        }

        public boolean isComplete() {
            return points.size() >= pointLimit;
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Point pp = null;
            Point p0 = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
                g.setColor(colors[i]);

                Point p = points.get(i);
                g.fillOval(p.x - 20, p.y - 20, 40, 40);

                pp = p;
            }

            if (drawLines && (points.size() > 1)) {
                p0 = points.get(0);
                pp = p0;
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                for (int i = 1; i < points.size(); i++) {
                    Point p = points.get(i);
                    g.drawLine(pp.x, pp.y, p.x, p.y);
                    pp = p;
                }
                g.drawLine(pp.x, pp.y, p0.x, p0.y);
            }
        }

        public class CircleMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
                if (points.size() < pointLimit) {
                    points.add(event.getPoint());
                    PaintPanel.this.repaint();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This works great. I need to separate the line drawing out. Lines should be drawn with a button click. That was my original dilemma.

Comment: In the JFrame class. This is a JPanel subclass. The button simply calls drawLines();
I did not include the JFrame class. It is pretty straight forward. Simple calls to this subclass.

Comment: @smh67: Now a button causes the lines to be drawn.

Comment: @Gilbert: Excellent and I was close to this as well. Much appreciated Gilbert!

Answer (score 0):

You don't call `repaint` when flag equals 3, so there is no call to the `paintComponent` method with the right condition (`drawCircles` `false` and `drawLines` `true`).
I suggest you to call `repaint` either when `flag` equals to 3 or and the end of `mouseClicked`.

Comment: Each click of the mouse should draw a circle. The previous circle(s) must be maintained. I attempted the change but still nothing renders.